# My EF CF Migration is generating 2 extra fields

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I use EF Code First Migration. I already have the `Request` class and I would like to add `RequestLinked` class.

Here is my `Request` class:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int RequestID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<RequestLinked> RequestLinkeds { get; set; } <-- ADDED
}
```

And below is my new `RequestLinked` class:

```
public class RequestLinked
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RequestRelatedID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual Request RequestRelated { get; set; }
}
```

I also added a rule inside my ObjectContext (OnModelCreating)

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<RequestLinked>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Request)
            .WithMany(p => p.RequestLinkeds)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Then I create a migration for this newly added model:

```
Add-Migration AddRequestLinkedTable
```

**The problem:** the generated (EF Migration) code is creating too much fields.

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.RequestLinkeds",
            c => new
                {
                    RequestID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    RequestRelatedID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Request_RequestID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    RequestRelated_RequestID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.RequestID, t.RequestRelatedID })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Requests", t => t.Request_RequestID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Requests", t => t.RequestRelated_RequestID)
            .Index(t => t.Request_RequestID)
            .Index(t => t.RequestRelated_RequestID);
    }
```

I didn't understand why I got `Request_RequestID` and `RequestRelated_RequestID` fields.

Note that I already perform the same steps inside another project and the migration plan generated didn't include these 2 extra fields.

Any ideas?

Thanks anyway.

---

UPDATE

As suggested by 3dd I marked RequestRelatedID with [ForeignKey("RequestRelated")] and [ForeignKey("Request")] with RequestID.

Now I got the migration plan below:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.RequestLinkeds",
            c => new
                {
                    RequestID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    RequestRelatedID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Request_RequestID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.RequestID, t.RequestRelatedID })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Requests", t => t.RequestID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Requests", t => t.RequestRelatedID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Requests", t => t.Request_RequestID)
            .Index(t => t.RequestID)
            .Index(t => t.RequestRelatedID)
            .Index(t => t.Request_RequestID);

    }
```

So 1 extra field disappeared. That's better but one remains...

Please note that on my `Request` class I have the key defined as `virtual`. I don't know if this is problematic... I tried to remove this `virtual` but still the same problem.

---

UPDATE 2

Finally I got it working by adjusting my ObjectContext like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<RequestLinked>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Request)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Try marking `RequestRelatedID` with `[ForeignKey("RequestRelated")]` and same with `RequestID`

Comment: @3dd I tried as you suggested and updated my question to show results.

Comment: Did you mark them correctly `RequestID` should have [ForeignKey("Request")]

Comment: Yes. But finally I got it working by adjusting the rule inside my ObjectContext. I update my question to show it. Thanks anyway.